# Fixing boot performance issues in Windows 7 64-bit

Tags: windows-7, boot

After installing Windows 7 Service Pack 1 updates, my boot performance reduced. I monitored the boot events and fixed many issues, but there're still issues which I am unable to fix. Before the logon screen, I get a black blank screen for one minute. It doesn't happen when I boot to another instance of Windows 7.

Take a look at these issues:

**Critical for Event Id 100**

[image]

**Warning for Event Id 108**

[image]

**Warning for Event Id 101**

[image]

**My system specifications:**

- Intel Core i7 840QM CPU (1.87GHz with Turbo Boost upto 3.2GHz; 4 physical + 4 virtual cores)
- 6GB RAM
- 7200RPM HDD with more than 50GB free in system drive
- ATI Mobility Radeon HD 5470 GPU

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry to keep this question open...
This problem was fixed a long ago by subsequent Windows Update.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a long shot, but have a look at [eventid.net](http://www.eventid.net) - all the errors have either been described or link to Microsoft site. Also, Blackviper's guide is a good read at http://www.blackviper.com/2010/12/17/black-vipers-windows-7-service-pack-1-service-configurations/

Comment: eventid.net is useful, but it also doesn't have information for last two events mentioned in question.

Answer (score 1):

[How to diagnose slow booting or logon in Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/250267/how-to-diagnose-slow-booting-or-logon-in-windows-7/250273#250273)

Do not do the performance analysis, but check the boot analysis section there. You need to do the first two steps of the performance analysis first, and then run the commands in the document I linked as an administrator. You most likely want to try to do a (re)boot cycle trace...

Comment: I've already done it to fix other problems related to this, but I'm unable to fix these three problems I mentioned in question.

Comment: @Sachin: I can't help you further if you don't provide the traces...