# Computer starts up slower even though I checked which programs are launched

Tags: windows-7, boot, speed

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to diagnose slow booting or logon in Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/250267/how-to-diagnose-slow-booting-or-logon-in-windows-7)

When I log into my computer it takes longer for all the background programs to finish loading than it used to. I tried using msconfig but I don't see any that can be disabled. Is there a program that tells you how long an application takes to launch at startup and gives the option to disable it?

I noticed things became slower after installing Cold Fusion but I uninstalled it.

Could it be certain programs, such as Avast Security, take a variable length of time to startup; for example if there are many updates?

Comment: An antivirus can definitely slow down the boot time of Windows, however it is a necessary evil. Have you tried defragmenting your hard drive?

Comment: It says 1% framgented.

Answer (score 1):

Few things to check:

See if [system logs](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/What-information-appears-in-event-logs-Event-Viewer) shows any errors or warnings. If any found then check what program/service generated error and when it is happening. In this case you are propably interested about events that happened just after bootup.

Check your harddrive for errors, not only bad sectros but for any SMART error too. If SMART events (read errors, crc corrections, seek failures, ...) counts high then there might be problem with hdd. See [How can I read my hard drive's SMART status in Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/q/29240/132604)

[Disable services](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_service#Managing_services) that you dont need, you can also use [Sysinternals Autoruns](http://live.sysinternals.com/) to do this.

Also watch out for RAM usage, CPU usage, disk usage and network usage during and just after startup. See [this article](http://itexpertvoice.com/home/what%E2%80%99s-taking-so-long-how-to-fight-slow-startup-times-in-windows-7/) and/or [Technet forum](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/w7itproperf/thread/7d226888-7e0c-43ab-aa37-dabf45983ead).

Answer (score 1):

Try Soluto. I've used it before and it seems to be what you're looking for. Basically you boot your computer and it logs how much boot time a startup item hogs up, displaying it to you once the computer is booted.

https://www.soluto.com/

also check for common problems like spyware, viruses, etc.