# System Idle is at 99%, Physical memory at 40%: why so slow?

Tags: windows-7, performance, windows-domain

I have a Win 7 32-bit Pro machine joined to a domain on a 10/100 ethernet connection.   At times this machine runs all sorts of slow.  For example, it took it 20 seconds for a command prompt to pull up, not to mention the other 15 seconds for the start bar to recognize that I clicked on it.  There are a few times where it took almost 10 minutes for the machine to even prompt for a password after powering it on.  There are various other situations in which the computer exhibits it's "slowness".

Inspecting task manager does not reveal anything obvious.  All other processes combined consumes < 1% in an idle state, and physical memory sits around 30%-40% consumed.  On the other hand, the System Event View reveals that several process are reporting `X service entered the stopped state` and `X service entered the start state` at various times.  Some other errors in the event viewer that reveals symptoms of the

```
Event ID: 7011

A timeout (30000 milliseconds) was reached while waiting for a transaction response from the X service.
```

There were several of these errors where the `X` serice was `SmcService`, `IAStorDataMgrSvc`, `Microsoft .Net Framework NGEN v4.0.30319_X86`, a few others.  I don't think that these services are causing the problem.  Rather there's something thats causing this services to time out.  What on earth is going on?

Comment: I/O / Interrupts most likely, you can [figure out which through performance analysis](http://superuser.com/a/250273/9666).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that Symantec Endpoint Protection is the culprit. Unintsalling the program and rebooting made it seem like a new computer again (as it should being only 6 months old).

Still, I am unable to find the cause for it to slow down.  There are no other virus scans on the computer, not even Microsft's Security Essentials.  This is all I have for now.

Answer (score 0):

The two things have nothing to do with each other. Idle is talking about CPU usage, not memory. It seems that you have identified the issue though, there is something wrong with these services (or a common dependency).

I would try to disable them one by one, and see if that changes anything. Additionally, I would try leaving the domain, booting in safe mode, and booting without network access.