# What is Windows 7 service dependency tree?

Tags: windows-7, services

Is there a chart or a list of Windows 7 Profesional built-in services and their dependencies?  I manually did this in the past with Windows XP when I had time, but there seems to be a couple dozen more services in Windows 7 and time is not on my side.  A quick google search did not yeild anything.

I am trying to figure out why the my event log is showing so many services are start and stopping related to this [question](https://superuser.com/questions/445353/system-idle-is-at-99-physical-memory-at-40-why-so-slow).

**EDIT:**
Any Updates?

Comment: Interestingly enough, [Black Viper](http://www.blackviper.com/service-configurations/black-vipers-windows-7-service-pack-1-service-configurations/) doesn't seem to have such a definitive list (though you can click the individual services to see their dependencies–which may be faster than waiting for the Service snap-in to do whatever it is that it does that takes it several seconds to populate the dependency tab). Maybe contact Black Viper to add a chart…

Comment: @Synetech This is a great start! Though, not sure how nicely dependcies will fit into his chart given the one-to-many relationships of services.  Still, might be worth bothering him.

Comment: I was thinking of a separate graph as opposed to the main chart. Hmm, I haven't used GraphVis in a while…

Answer (score 2):

A good start would be the [services groups](http://www.windowsitpro.com/article/tips/jsi-tip-0260-what-is-a-service-group-). Windows services are willing within groups to load according to them dependencies:

> A Service Group is a collection of similar services that are loaded
> together at startup. Most services that appear in the
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\CurrentControlSet\Services subkey are part of a
> Service Group. Windows NT loads one Service Group at a time. Services
> that are not in a group are loaded after all Service Groups are
> loaded.
>
> The HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\CurrentControlSet\Control\ServiceGroupOrder
> subkey determines the order in which Service Groups are loaded. The
> List value is a REG_MULT_SZ entry that specifies the Service Group
> order.
>
> The HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\CurrentControlSet\Control\GroupOrderList subkey
> determines the order in which services within a Service Group are
> loaded. Services in a Service Group are assigned a tag, a unique
> numeric value within a Service Group which determines the service load
> order. Each value entry in GroupOrderList represents a Service Group.
> The value of the entry is a series of tags in a specified order. The
> first entry in this REG_BINARY value is the number of services in the
> group, followed by the tags in load sequence. If you look at
> PointerPort you can see that there are 3 services in the group and
> that the service with tag 02 is loaded first, followed by the service
> with tag 01 and then tag 03.
>
> At a service level, the
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\CurrentControlSet\Services\ServiceName subkeys
> contain:
>
> Group - this REG_SZ specifies the Service Group name
> that a service belongs to.
>
> tag - this REG_DWORD specifies the service load sequence.
>
> DependOnGroup  - this REG_MULTI_SZ entry defines the Service Groups which must be loaded
> succesfully before this service loads.
>
> DependOnService - this REG_MULTI_SZ entry defines services that must be loaded successfully before this service loads.

Comment: That still requires manually building the graph which they want to avoid. (They already know how to do it manually.) To be honest, I would be surprised if there were not some pre-made graph in the MSDN docs or something.

Answer (score 1):

Once upon a time I'd found a tool that did exactly what you're asking for (back when Windows XP was new), but I don't have a copy anymore and I can't find it.  It didn't handle service groups though, so it would be of limited utility.

The closest thing I can find now is the [Windows Service Dependency Viewer](http://svcdependencyviewer.codeplex.com/).  It's not ideal though.

Answer (score 0):

There are PowerShell functions that can enumerate depending and required services. Stumbled over this when I was searching for a solution to the same problem: `.DependentServices` and `.ServicesDependedOn`

Here's a full script (adapted from the [original/source](https://dkalemis.wordpress.com/2015/03/02/visualize-the-services-graph-of-your-windows-os/)):

```
# https://dkalemis.wordpress.com/2015/03/02/visualize-the-services-graph-of-your-windows-os/
#   replace "DisplayName" with "Name" ore vice versa.

function List-DependentServices ($inputService, $inputPadding)
{
    if ($inputService.DependentServices)
    {
        $padding = "   " + $inputPadding
        $output = $padding + "/\ is required by these services:"
        $output
        $padding = "   " + $padding
 
        foreach ($ds in $inputService.DependentServices)
        {
            $output = $padding + $ds.Name
            $output
            List-DependentServices $ds $padding
        }
    }
}
 
function List-ServicesDependedOn ($inputService, $inputPadding)
{
    if ($inputService.ServicesDependedOn)
    { 
        $padding = "   " + $inputPadding
        $output = $padding + "\/ depends on these services:"
        $output
        $padding = "   " + $padding
 
        foreach ($rs in $inputService.ServicesDependedOn)
        {  
            $output = $padding + $rs.Name
            $output
            List-ServicesDependedOn $rs $padding
        }
    } 
}
 
$services = Get-Service
foreach ($service in $services)
{
    $output = $service.Name
    $output
    List-DependentServices $service ""
    List-ServicesDependedOn $service ""
}
```

And this can help to execute it (redirect output `> toText.file`)

```
powershell.exe "-Command" "if((Get-ExecutionPolicy ) -ne 'AllSigned') { Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope Process Bypass }; & '.\ServiceGraphRecursively.ps1'"
```

The original author went a step further and explains how to parse the text output from this script into an actual graph.