# How to speed boot windows 7 when there are many wifi hot point?

Tags: windows-7

I connect to internet with my wireless network, but there are many other wifi hot points in my apartment,I find Windows 7 spend a lot of time to search all wifi hot points when system start, so the boot of Windows 7 is very slow.
How can I do? Thanks!

Comment: This question is extremely confused. Having a large amount of WiFi hotspots close to you does not affect your boot time what so ever.

Comment: What have you attempted already to rectify this or confirm it's your WiFi?  If you disable your wireless adapter is booting faster? If not, then it's not your Wifi (or WiFi netwarks around you) that's causing it and you should probably look into questions like [How to diagnose slow booting or logon in Windows 7?](http://superuser.com/questions/250267/how-to-diagnose-slow-booting-or-logon-in-windows-7)

Comment: analyze the boot with xbootmgr and look what is slow in detail: http://www.msfn.org/board/index.php?showtopic=140247

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are many neighboring wireless networks in your area, make sure your router is on a channel with as little interference as possible. You can use an application like [inSSIDer](http://www.metageek.net/products/inssider/) to get an overview.

Also, check the manufacturer site to see if newer drivers are available for your wireless adapter.

As bigbadonk420 mentioned, having a lot of wireless networks nearby does not technically slow down boot times for Windows, but it certainly can make it feel a little sluggish if you have to wait long for it to connect to your accesspoint, and you want to access the internet straight away.

(Obviously, connecting via an ethernet cable, if at all possible, would also solve the problem, and improve your connection speed. I personally try to avoid wireless as much as possible.)