# Why my lenovo i5 laptop perform poor as compared to my i3 desktop

Tags: windows-7, laptop, performance, 64-bit, cpu

I have lenovo laptop and desktop which has following configurations:

**LENOVO LAPTOP:**

i5 3250 3rd gen cpu @ 2.60GHz 2.60GHz 64 bit architecture

window 7 32 bit

4 GB Ram

**Desktop:**

core(TM) i3 540 @ 3.07GHz 3.06GHz 32 bit architecture

window 7 32 bit

4Gb Ram

laptop has higher configuration as compared to desktop but desktop performance like booting, opening programs etc is much better than laptop. what is reason of that

Is this due to 32 bit window 7 on 64 bit laptop or due to clock speed ?
if someone have suggestions regarding improve performance of laptop please help me

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to diagnose slow booting or logon in Windows 7?](http://superuser.com/questions/250267/how-to-diagnose-slow-booting-or-logon-in-windows-7)

Comment: Why do you say the laptop has a higher configuration compared to the desktop? The desktop has a CPU that benchmarks 80% faster. They have the same OS and RAM. Your expectation doesn't seem to be based on anything.

Comment: david i'm novice in pc hardware i just think i5>i3 :)

Comment: @GILL Well, that's nonsense. Whether Intel calls a product a Core i3 or a Core i5 has to do with where it fits in the current product lineup at the time of its release, not its absolute performance. There are Core i5's from 2009 that, obviously, can't possibly compete with a brand new Core i3 built on technology that is four years newer. And, of course, both product lines include both desktop and laptop CPUs -- desktop CPUs prioritize performance while laptop CPUs have to balance that heavily against power consumption.

Answer (score 1):

Things like booting or opening programs are mostly IO oriented. If you cares a lot about these, replace you HDD with an SSD. My pentium laptop with an SSD boots within 30 secs.

32bit windows cannot make full use of your 4GB RAM. 64bit will do. But the difference is insignificant. Switch to 64bit OS if you want to add more memory.