# How to discover what is slowing down my computer's startup?

Tags: windows-7, performance

I use windows 7 and every install I've ever had starts to start up really slow after several months of use. Instead of trying to speed it up (like I already did with pretty much every widespread tweek out there), I want to know **what** is slowing down my windows 7 startup. It goes a good minute after the logon screen, with nothing running, with 0% - 1% CPU usage and only after that period of time it opens the programs that I've already clicked, which leads me to believe there's something deliberately delaying my programs initialization and I want to know what

Comment: Have you tried to disable all non-required startup items does it help? I have the exact same installation I had 10 years ago and the startup speed is exactly the same.  I have even upgraded the same installation from Windows Vista, Windows 7, Windows 8,and now Windows 8.1.  Your need to reinstall Windows every couple months is abnormal

Comment: I did disabled them and it helped marginally. Still takes too long

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned by @techie007, there is another thread already at [How to diagnose slow booting or logon in Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/250267/how-to-diagnose-slow-booting-or-logon-in-windows-7). This article mentions using the [Windows Performance Analysis Tools](http://cid-d8ad98ab9f8ec6ca.office.live.com/browse.aspx/.Public/XPerf), **but this link appears to be broken so this is not a viable solution.**

Don't give up so quickly though. As the thread also mentions, you can try [Soluto](https://www.soluto.com/), which I use personally to diagnose issues on my laptop. It monitors and makes suggestions about how to reduce start/boot up time as well as remind you about other sysadmin tasks, such as installing Windows or application updates for your installed programs. It monitors computer temperature, antivirus condition, and other system vitals also.

The program [BootVis](http://www.majorgeeks.com/files/details/bootvis.html) was originally made for Windows XP, but it may or may not work on Windows 7, so give it a spin if you'd like. It was originally released by Microsoft to computer manufacturers to optimize their construction of Windows computers, and has since been discontinued. It offers graphs on CPU, disk activity, etc. of what happens during boot time. Be warned though, it might be too old to work.

Finally, if you don't want to throw any more stuff on your computer, which is probably part of your problem, you can try using the built-in system Event Viewer. The full instructions on how to use Event Viewer to track and diagnose boot times can be found in [this TechRepublic article](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/windows-and-office/use-windows-7-event-viewer-to-track-down-issues-that-cause-slower-boot-times/3253/).

Answer (score 0):

Kinda answering my own question. I used [Soluto](https://www.soluto.com/) and it is amazing. 2 top offenders: online banking protection module, and windows live ID