# Why does my computer sometimes boot up faster or slower?

Tags: windows, boot, performance

I'm pretty curious, not a problem per say but it would be good to know.

Sometimes when i restart or boot up my computer, it would boot slower or faster than other times.

Is there an explanation or theory to this phenomena?

***NOTE :*** *My computer is pretty new. 1 month since i bought it*

EDIT (More Info) : My computer sometimes restarts slow after using for a while, for example : 5-7 hours. Sometimes start extremely slow or extremely fast if i shut it down and stop using it for 6-10 hours.

When the computer is booted up, overall performance is what i or anyone would expect from my system specs.

SPECS :

CPU : Intel Core i7-5960X

GPU : GeForce GTX TITAN X

Display : ASUS PB287Q, 3840X2160 Resolution

Storage : OCZ Z-Drive R3 P84 SSD and WD Green WD10EZRX 1TB HDD

Comment: Elaborate your question with some examples like when your system is fast and when slow. Blindly we can not suggest you, because we don't know what is your system configuration and what are the programs you have installed.

Comment: Combination of the watched pot never boils syndrome and differences between reboots, cold starts, and waking from sleep and/or hibernation.  If you'd like to analyze it deeper than that you'd need to collect the metrics on each scenario over some period of time. Armed with that you'd have a question, right now it's just blind speculation

Comment: Also, you could have Windows updates being completed, etc.  There is boot diagnostic/optimization software that will track and report what's happening during startup and how long each thing is taking.

Comment: Question has been downvoted to at least -2, but then brought back up to at least zero.  I realize that, upon first glance, the question may look way too open-ended.  However, this does seem like a legitimate question that could have multiple useful answers that describe the general processes/reasons.  e.g., fixer1234's just-added comment.  I could see this question having potential for a really well-written answer, which could be very useful for many people.  (Hopefully this happens: hopefully someone will write such a gem.)

Comment: If data is available from Windows on boot times and factors that modify it( good to know), and its collected and provided to the site it could be a good question and I for one would be interested in the responses.

Comment: Added more info in original post

Comment: @TOOGAM, if the OP is trying to solve an actual problem on their computer and the question contains sufficient diagnostic information, that would be a good, on-topic question.  From that perspective, the question is too broad to answer as-is.  If the question is asking, "What are all the things that could affect startup time", that's not a good fit for many reasons (questions looking for lists, theoretical rather than actual, general learning, etc.).  However, watch this become a HNQ, get ridiculously voted up, and somebody will post an encyclopedic answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate: your question is slightly different, but the answers are basically the same as this question http://superuser.com/questions/250267/how-to-diagnose-slow-booting-or-logon-in-windows .  Additional tools: https://www.pcsteps.com/921-measure-windows-boot-time/, http://www.guidingtech.com/2955/fix-slow-windows-startup-boot-performance-diagnostics/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are myriad possibilities, including but not limited to:

- System starting from sleep, hybernate or off.
- Installation of patches on boot
- DHCP lease renegotiation
- Periodic filesystem check
- BIOS detecting config changes
- Contents of drive cache (if using hard rive with built in ssd cache)
- System slowdown related to temperature (unlikely)

Comment: Nicely done, @fixer1234

Comment: I actually checked my computer, and it is because of temperature. I usually use my PC 12 hours a day.

Comment: If temperature is causing this slowdown there is something wrong (and you should attend to it).  If parts of a computer are getting so slow they throttle back, you really need to fix the cooling problem.  (Maybe reapply heatsink with themal glue, clear dust or replace fans etc).