# How to speed up the booting process in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, boot, start-screen

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to diagnose a slow booting laptop](https://superuser.com/questions/163525/how-to-diagnose-a-slow-booting-laptop)
>   [How to diagnose slow booting or logon in Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/250267/how-to-diagnose-slow-booting-or-logon-in-windows-7)

When I turn on the computer, I have to wait about 1 minute to the boot process. Can I speed up the booting process?  My OS is Windows 7.

Whether by removing the start screen in the Windows 7 can speed up the boot process? .

Comment: The startscreen is just there for loading stuff in the background. Removing it and going back to lists of output from the boot does not speed-up the startup I suppose.

Comment: Come on that's the best speed for Windows-7 boot. But you can switch to Windows-8 if you really want to boot more fast then 1 minute.

Answer (score 2):

When a Windows computer starts up, it will start any programs or services which are configured to launch at startup, in addition to loading the operating system. Some of these may not be necessary and disabling their launch could speed things up a bit. A useful tool for looking at the startup configuration is [Autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx). You may not know when you review the list if a particular program or service is necessary but you could post a new question or follow-up comment to ask for more information about the effect of disabling one.

But my suggestion for your issue would be to consider using two features of Windows which work very well and which can easily speed your startup time - [Sleep and Hibernate](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/Sleep-and-hibernation-frequently-asked-questions) - rather than shutting down your computer as often.

Most computers will wake from Sleep almost instantly. One possible disadvantage is that the computer will use a small amount of power even when it is sleeping. If you use Hibernate, it will take a little longer to resume (but not as long as from a cold boot) but one advantage is that the computer will not use any power while it is hibernating.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try my answer:

1. right click on My Computer, and then properties.
2. advanced setting, and then chhose advanced.
3. choose settings on menu Startup and recovery.
4. in the option "Time to display list of operating systems:", set the value to "3" seconds(because the minimal value is 3, if I try to change value to "0", the value automatically changes to "3").
5. ok, and try to reboot your system, you will feel the difference.

viola :)

Comment: This would only help if there was more than one OS in the list which is probably not.

Answer (score 0):

Defragment boot files automatically Make sure the boot file terdefragment automatically, so the faster the process will start.

1. Access the registry editor
2. Press (Windows+r) in keyboard and then typing with "regedit"
3. Find the key below: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE | Software | Microsoft | Dfrg | BootOptimizeFunction 4. Note that there is a right side panel key OptimizeComplete
4. Double click the key and change the value data to be Yes.
5. Close the registry editor and restart the computer.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try this way :

1. Click Start Menu, then typed "regedit" in the search box programs and files.
2. then click the result above (regedit).
3. Once entered into the Register, search HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\
   Control\SessionManager\MemoryManagement\PrefetchParameters.
4. In the right pane, double click "EnablePrefetcher", then change value to 2 and click OK
5. In the right pane, double click "EnableSuperfetch", then change value to 2 and click OK
6. Exit the registry and restart your PC/Laptop for the changes to take effect. Feel the different after n before the changes.

Comment: Could you perhaps explain what changing those values does?

Comment: if I tried your suggestion, how do I know if the boot process faster than ever before?